# Suppose A and B are finite sets and $f : A \rightarrow B$ is surjective. Is it possible that |A| < |B|?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand better what surjective functions is from a set $A$ to a set $B$, and from what I understood, it basically means this:

> A function is subjective (onto) from set $A$ to set $B$ if for each $b
> > \in B$, there exists an $a \in A$ for which $b = f(a)$. Note that all
>   elements in $B$ are used. The function $f$ may map more than 1 element
>   of $A$ to the same element of $B$.

For the last statement, I would say that $|A| < |B|$ is false, because $A$ can have more elements than $B$...

Comment: Subjection is basically if you have one of "this" you have one of "that."

Answer (score 3):

The set $f(A)$ contains at most $|A|$ elements. If $f(A)=B$ then $|A|\ge |f(A)|=|B|$.

Comment: Yes, we cannot have both $|A|\ge |B|$ and $|A|<|B|$. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct.  If $|A| < |B|$ and there were a surjective function between them, then there would be branching from the domain, so it would not be a function.

Here is a good image of this exact situation.

[image]

Comment: This is an image of something that is not a function. If we were to assume the $|X|<|Y|$ and there was a surjective map, then we would get an instant contradiction.