# Is it true that the relation |A| < |B| is a sufficient condition for claiming that $f$ is a bijection?

Tags: functions, relations

This is an exercise of an assignment I have:

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are finite sets and $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective. Is it
>   true that the relation “$|A| < |B|$” is a sufficient condition for
>   claiming that $f$ is a bijection? Justify your answer.

And this is my answer:

> No. In fact, if $|A| < |B|$, then there should exist at least $1$ element
>   of $A$ that points to more than $1$ element of $B$, since all elements of $B$
>   must be pointed (surjective), but this is not a function,
>   because the same element of $A$ point to different elements of $B$.

Is my answer correct? I don't know if the question actually is asking for a proof or what, and if my answer is a proof, if correct.

Comment: What is $f$ here? Also if $|A|<|B|$, then there can be no bijection between $A$ and $B$!

Comment: Not the down voter, but this is exactly the same as this question, posted 5 minutes ago http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073550/relation-proofs-on-finite-set

Comment: If $\lvert A \rvert < \lvert B \rvert$, how exactly can $f$ be surjective?

Comment: Either way, both this question and that question have a mistake, in that they have $|A|\lt |B|$ rather than $|A|\le|B|$

Comment: I am having a very hard time to understand your question. You begin with "This is my answer". Your answer to what?

Comment: Also how is this different from [your question from yesterday](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072205/suppose-a-and-b-are-finite-sets-and-f-a-rightarrow-b-is-surjective-is-it-p)?

Answer (score 2):

If $\lvert A \rvert < \lvert B \rvert$, then you cannot have any surjective function $f\colon A\to B$ anyway, and the question is vacuous.
(the image $f(A)$ of $A$ by *any* function $f$ must satisfy $\lvert f(A) \rvert \leq \lvert A \rvert$, with equality when $f$ is injective).